# Ajax Request to handle browser timeout + PHP long process

Tags: php, ajax, timeout

I have a process which takes approx 20 minutes to process but before the process completes brower timeouts and user remains in question whether the process is complete or not.

Need a working example to work around this.

Is there a way to send a ajax resquest and server responds with 200 , the long process contnues in background.

Please help

Comment: I have an excel file to process in php which will takes approx 20 minutes to process which i initiate through an ajax call, browser responds with timeout killing the process.need a workaround wherein i can send a ajax request and the php process can run in background and the polling the process to check if the process is complete.

Comment: did you send asynchronous AJAX or sync one? async request should not be timeout. Unless you leave the current page.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose **asynchronous AJAX request** would solve your issue since it runs in the background waiting for response from the server to perform callback function.

Remember **not leaving the page while AJAX running** in the background.

Comment: asking a user not to leave a page for 20 minutes will be difficult. Maybe the best way to handle this long process is to submit it, and notify the user when it's done (through email, for example). Waiting for something to be done is not the way things are done now, see our smartphones, they use notifications !